# Como fazer pra ordenar uma tabela em MySQL, junto com o comando de consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Queria saber se é possível ordenar uma tabela em MySQL, sendo, nessa mesma linha de código uma consulta de busca.

```
 $ resultado_consulta="SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5";
```

Queria ordenar o ano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então a "N" formas de ordenar, eu não recomendo fazer só um campo de ano, pois isso pode te dar problemas no futuro, principalmente quando for ter que exibir um relatório por período de registros. Você pode separar por vírgula:`order by id desc, ano desc` etc... Você precisa ter um campo de data do tipo: DATE, DATETIME, ou TIMESTAMP. No caso eu chamei de `data_registro`. Se vc quer ordenar apenas por ano, basta fazer isso para o pegar do mais recente para o mais antigo (decrescente):

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' order by YEAR(data_registro) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Ou o inverso (ascendente):

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' order by YEAR(data_registro) ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Agora se você está se referindo a turma do aluno tipo: 1º ano, 2º ano, 3º ano...

Você pode fazer uma ordem assim:

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' order by FIELD(turma, '1º ano', '2º ano', '3º ano') ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda irmão! Sou novo no ramo da informática e tenho poucas experiência. Mas deus certo fazendo o seguinte código: "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' order by ano ASC LIMIT 5".

Answer (score 2):

Se a coluna chama `ano`:

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5 ORDER BY ano
```

O `ORDER BY` é a cláusula que fazer classificar pela ordem especificada. Se não tiver um índice adequado a operação pode demorar um pouco. Se demorar e a consulta ocorre com frequência é melhor criar um índice que ajude essa consulta. É algo mais avançado, mas fundamental no cenário descrito.

Se não tem o ano e sim uma data poderia pegar a data:

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5 ORDER BY YEAR(data)
```

Mas isso pode ser até mais complicado para o índice e não sei se o ano é tão importante assim, a data inteira pode resolver melhor porque classificaria pelo ano, então poderia só fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome_aluno LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5 ORDER BY data
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/OrderBy.sql).

É possível usar um `ASC` para dizer que é ascendente, mas isso é o padrão. A pergunta não diz se é o desejado.

O `LIKE` pode prejudicar bastante isso, ele é um terror usado assim, mas pode funcionar bem em alguns casos.

Se esse `$pesquisar` é um dado que vem de fora da aplicação, mesmo indiretamente, é inseguro usar aí e o servidor sofrerá uma invasão.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).